# Implementation of Numpy's Generator Class

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm trying to get some insights in how the random number generation in numpy works. However, the jump to definition does not work here: I'm always ending in some `.pyi` files only listing the function without the body.

Whats the recommended workflow for expanding functions here?

The generator itself seems to be written in Cython and in some `.pyx` files. Does this all arise because its basically written in Cython?

Comment: the important parts of numpy are mostly written in C, C++, and Cython (this is what makes it fast). I think there are even bits of Fortran. Numpy is fully open source, though: https://github.com/numpy/numpy I believe the `numpy.random` module is implemented here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/random/

Comment: You should also check out the docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html